# .Ignore babelrc in submodule

Tags: node.js, babeljs

I've got a client side code that transpiles down to ES5 for browser support.

I also have a server side application which also uses babel and transpiles for Node 8 support. We include the client side repo as a git sub-module so we can run select client side javascript modules server side too, isomorphic javascript.

When building the server side application how can I make the project root .babelrc file act as master and ignore all sub .babelrc files when importing from the client side modules? If I delete the sub-module .babelrc file it compiles just fine.

```
Exception has occurred: SyntaxError
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
    at createScript (vm.js:74:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:116:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:537:28)
```

It sounds like this is a known pain point but I don't know how people have solved it up until now.
https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/6766#issuecomment-342706807

Thanks

Comment: I would like to find out as well as I have the same problem. One way to do it would be to add a post install npm script that deletes the file.